# Postgres dblink_exec in trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, exec, dblink

I'm getting an error when a trigger is run and trying to run the following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new_sessions()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN
SELECT dblink_exec('dbname=billing  port=5432','INSERT INTO md.radacct_test(radacctid,acctsessionid,acctuniqueid,username) select New.radacctid,New.acctsessionid,New.acctuniqueid,New.username' );

    RETURN NULL;
    EXCEPTION    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE NOTICE 'insert_new_sessions SQL ERROR: %', SQLERRM;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error:

```
ERROR insert_new_sessions SQL ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have NEW inside the string, thus interpreted *as* a string? Try concatenating the NEW.xxx values with the rest of the string.
Eg. 
`INSERT INTO md.radacct_test(...) SELECT ' || NEW.radacctid ||', ' || NEW.acctsessionid || ', ' || NEW.acctuniqueid || ', ' || quote_nullable(NEW.username));`

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the OLD and NEW keywords are case sensitive.